# PHP I create a double variable then test it for equality and it does not match?

Tags: php, math, double

I can't figure out why this simple math does not work. Maybe something about PHP and numbers I am not getting?

```
$step=1.0;

$step+=0.1;

$substep=$step-(int)$step;

echo gettype($substep);

echo $substep;

if ($substep==0.1) { 

    echo "should be here";

} else {

    echo "but I end up here";

}
```

OUTPUT: double0.1but I end up here

Comment: what exact output do you expect?

Comment: Because of the way floats are represented internally, two floats (double) should not be tested for equality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)